# Selenium with Firefox Nightly Build

Tags: firefox, selenium

First, some context. I'm trying to run profile guided optimization with LLVM on Firefox, which means that I have to build the source with clang myself. I've thus downloaded Firefox and built it using mach from source.

However, when I try to use Selenium with my nightly build, it doesn't appear to be able to communicate with the browser. For example, the following code loads yahoo.com and then **hangs on driver.get() indefinitely.** I've tried using explicit and implicit waits and time.sleep() to get the code to move past driver.get(), but I can't find anything. This code works perfectly with the official release of Firefox, just not any version that I compile.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

# Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
binary = FirefoxBinary('/home/kevin/firefox/mozilla-central/obj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/dist/bin/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

sequence = ['http://www.yahoo.com', 'http://www.cnn.com', 'http://www.amazon.com', 'http://www.newegg.com', 'http://www.google.com']

for url in sequence:
    driver.get(url)

driver.quit()
```

To be clear, the driver is able to ask Firefox to load the first page in the sequence. However, it just hangs forever after that.

I've looked at other threads and tried updating Selenium and Firefox, but nothing has worked so far.

Is there any way to force Selenium to move forward? Failing that, are there any other browser automation frameworks that might be more cooperative with a nightly build of Firefox?