# Running Protractor against dev/trunk/master selenium server

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

**The Story:**

`Protractor` itself is coming with a [built-in `webdriver-manager` command line tool](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/2bde92b3e745e09ad3876932b2d187365e9aaa31/docs/tutorial.md#setup):

> The `webdriver-manager` is a helper tool to easily get an instance of a Selenium Server running. Use it to download the necessary binaries with:
>
> ```
> webdriver-manager update
> ```
>
> Now start up a server with:
>
> ```
> webdriver-manager start
> ```

According to `webdriver-manager` binary [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/bin/webdriver-manager), it uses [`config.json`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/config.json) to download a specific `selenium` package version into a `selenium` directory in the `Protractor` package root. For instance, now the config looks:

```
{
  "webdriverVersions": {
    "selenium": "2.48.2",
    "chromedriver": "2.20",
    "iedriver": "2.48.0"
  }
}
```

This config is then [manually updated](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/18e1f71a4dd868709f4e259e05a8a196921e22be) when new `selenium`, chrome or IE driver versions come out.

For this config, running `webdriver-manager update` would trigger a `selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar` to be downloaded.

**The Question:**

Is it possible to have `webdriver-manager` to install the currently [latest/dev/trunk/master `selenium` version](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium)? And, if not, how can I run protractor tests with the latest dev `selenium` package version?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without hacking the script quite a bit, and even then `master` does not include a built `.jar` file, so I believe you would need to compile one from master. This would definitely be handy :\

Comment: @NickTomlin I think you are right, it would require compiling the `jar` manually and then placing it under `node_modules/protractor/selenium`, may be replacing an existing one. I'll try that and get back here. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe if you can put this compilation logic into a Dockerfile I can potentially include it in [docker-selenium](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium) ;)

Comment: @LeoGallucci nice! Then may be we can also think about allowing nightly firefox builds to be specified with, for example, `-e nightly`..but I'm still not sure how to make the nightly firefox work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446868/running-protractor-against-a-nightly-firefox-build. Thanks.